# Embarcadero 10.2 Android apps not works on my phone but works another phone

Tags: android, delphi

I have Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.2 without any updates. I created a simple Android app with a button and a showmessage('Hello World'); but when I connect my phone and install my app to my phone via USB the app freeze on the splash screen and nothing happen. I try to run my simple app on another Anroid phone and it is works perfect. I have a HTC E9+ with Android 5.0.2 version. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is your device even supported? Take a look at [Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)

Comment: "*I have Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.2 **without any updates***" - the RTM release of 10.2 breaks Android projects pretty badly. You need to install the various hotfixes that have been released, both for the IDE itself and for FMX

Comment: Thank you, but I changed over time to Delphi 10.2 update 3 but the situation is the same. On my Android device display the splash screen and freeze.